# Visualizing road line segments within specific borders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, visualisation, census, road, borders

I have a perhaps very simple ArcGIS question: How can I make the road line segments start or stop at the edge of the city's Census Block Groups?

[image]

Comment: Geoprocessing - Clip roads by city polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you the Clip (Analysis) tool, use this tool to cut out a piece of one feature class using one or more of the features in another feature class as a cookie cutter. You can read up more [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm) as provided by ESRI. Also, keep in mind, the attribute values from the input feature classes will be copied to the output feature class. Here are a few examples ESRO provides as visual representation of the Clip tool.

A polygon shapefile clipped by another polygon shapefile

[image]

A polyline shapefile clipped by a polygon shapefile

[image]

A point shapefile clipped by a polygon shapefile

[image]

Comment: And to do the opposite (you mentioned you might want them to start at the boundary, also), use the Symmetrical Difference Tool and select all the features that don't intersect.